# Probability in quantum mechanics and is it possible its not conserved

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

Can someone give an example of a physical situation in real life where quantum mechanics is applicable but probability is not conserved.

Comment: Can you explain more how you came to the conjecture such a cattywampus situation is possible?

Answer (score 4):

No. Probability has to be conserved in quantum mechanics. The technical term for this is [unitarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_(physics)), and by construction the dynamical equations of quantum mechanics preserve unitarity.

It is possible to talk about non-unitary evolution as a model of processes such as particle decay. But in this situation one always has in mind that they are only modeling part of a system, and ignoring another part. For example, the Hamiltonian for a muon by itself which can decay is non-unitary. But the full Hamiltonian, including the muon and its decay products, is unitary.

Comment: Does conservation of probability mean that by Noether's theorem there is some sort of magic transformation which leaves a probabilistic system invariant? if so, what would it be?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Unitarity isn't really a symmetry so I don't think it follows from Noether's theorem. However I think the probability current in quantum mechanics can be thought of as a Noether current for the $U(1)$ symmetry (rotate the wavefunction by an overall phase) if you write a Lagrangian for the Schrodinger equation, at least in simple cases. (It's been a while since I thought about that though)

Answer (score 1):

Particle decay.  Dirac discussed this in [his very last paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02214096.pdf)

> Dirac PA. The future of atomic physics. International journal of theoretical physics. 1984;23(8):677-81.

and non-unitary representations in quantum mechanics have been explored in this context in the 60s and 70s.  The difficulty physically is loss of unitarity, and mathematically non-unitary representations are not always easy to construct.  See for instance, [this paper on unstable particles](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1973__19_4_341_0.pdf)

> Raczka R. A theory of relativistic unstable particles. In: Annales de l'IHP Physique théorique 1973 (Vol. 19, No. 4, pp. 341-356).